# Add constant to a mock in PHPUnit

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, constants

Is it possible to add a class constant to a mock using PHPUnit?

Here an example:

```
class SomeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        $mock = $this->getMock( 'SomeClass' );
        // Here I'd like to add a constant to $mock; something like
        // $mock::FOOBAR;
    }
}
```

Does any of you know how can I get this behavious to work?

Thx!

Comment: Would the Reflection class accomplish what you want?  http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Answer (score 2):

This question has been around a while with no answers, but I ran into this same problem. This does not appear to be possible; however, there's at least one dirty work-around:

In your test file

```
<?php

class SomeClass {
    const FOOBAR = 'foobar';
}

class SomeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        $mock = $this->getMock( 'SomeClass' );
    }
}

// tests

?>
```

Then, you use your mocked object for mocked functionality, and you use the class constant the same way you would have originally. For example:

```
// Call a method on mocked object
// (would need to add this method to your mock, of course)
$mock->doSomething();
// Use the constant
$fooBar = SomeClass::FOOBAR;
```

This is dirty, so I'm sure things could get pretty messed up if you're using some sort of autoloading that tries to load the actual `SomeClass` class, but this will work "fine" if you're not loading the original `SomeClass`.

I'm definitely interested to hear other solutions as well as get some feedback on just how dirty this really is.

Comment: Probably `SomeClass` should be declared like **`class SomeClassMock extends SomeClass`** for this approach to work the way it supposed to and `SomeClass` itself shouldn't be `final` in its essence.